Why are the p-local Adams operations $\psi^q$ with $(p,q)=1$ stable?
In the famous work of Adams, Switzer and Harris, the stable Adams operations are being described as a map of spectra. (Which they, obviously, correspond to.)
More precisely, or at least that is how I understand it, we need a map of spectra $\psi^k\colon K\wedge M\to K\wedge M$,  where $M$ is the "Moore spectrum" in the sense that one takes a "Moore space" $M_2$ determined by having its reduced singular homology groups concentrated in degree 2 and that group $H_2(M_2)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$; and then one takes $M$ as the $\Omega$-spectrum associated to the suspension spectrum of $M_2$, shifted by two degrees to the left. They say that one can define that map $\psi^k$ by assigning $\frac 1{k^{n}}\colon K_{2n}\wedge M_2\to K_{2n}\wedge M_2$ to the $2n$-th component.
Now I've got two questions:

Why do the multiplication map $k$ of Moore spaces multiplicating the fundamental group by $k$ even exist? Is taking the "Moore space" of arbitrary abelian groups a functor $\mathfrak{Ab}\to\mathfrak{CW-complexes}$?
Why is the stability criterion $\Sigma\circ \psi^k=\psi^k\circ\Sigma$ fulfilled? Is it possible to explain this explicitly?

